# How can Pareto(alpha = 5, x_min = 2) be heavy-tailed where alpha is the shape parameter or the tail index?

Tags: pareto-distribution, heavy-tailed, shape-parameter

Point 1 : It's known that, usually, when the tail-index (alpha) is between 0 and 2, of a certain data set, the distribution is considered as heavy-tailed.

Point 2 : It's know that Pareto distribution is an example for heavy tailed distribution.

Let's consider Pareto distribution with alpha = 5 (say x_min = 2 for instance). Since 5 > 2, isn't point 2 become contradictory with point 1?

Comment: The two points are using the term "heavy tailed" in distinctly different senses.

Comment: Do you mean, alpha in Pareto is different from alpha in a typical heavy-tailed distribution?

Comment: No. I literally mean what I wrote -- that the meaning of the phrase "heavy tailed" is different in those two points.

Comment: Could you please share some link or any source of information, where I can get the distinct meanings? Thank you for the feedback.